# How to make a bi-table MYSQL select query based on longitude, latitude and radius?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. workers table and jobs table. The worker table accepts `latitude`, `longitude` and `work radius`. The jobs table has `latitude` and `longitude`. I need a select query that gets the rows from the jobs table, but within the `work radius` of the worker table.

Below is the structure of the tables and what I have so far, which is to select from a table based on latitude and longitude.

Thanks for any help.

Worker table:

```
CREATE TABLE "worker" (
  "id" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "latitude" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "longitude" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "work_radius" int(25) NOT NULL,
  "address" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Jobs Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "jobs" (
  "id" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "latitude" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "longitude" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "address" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Select query:

```
$jobs_load = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT
    `*`,
    (
        6371 *
        acos(
            cos( radians( :lat_id ) ) *
            cos( radians( `lat_id` ) ) *
            cos(
                radians( `long_id` ) - radians( :long_id )
            ) +
            sin(radians(:lat_id) *
            sin(radians(`lat_id`))
        )
    ) `work_radius`
FROM
    `jobs`
HAVING
    `work_radius` < :work_radius
ORDER BY
    `work_radius`
LIMIT
    25");
```

Comment: You sure you are using MySQL? Qouted table names and columns arn't normally supported by MySQL.. unless MySQL has added "ANSI" in his sql-mode.

Comment: Yes, I'm using MYSQL and apparently, it's supported on my server. :)

Comment: In simple words find all available jobs for a worker in his sphere based on his current coordinates and his permissible range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over all the `worker` then for each worker find jobs within its "range" , try this

```
$conn = $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM worker");

$allWorkers = [];

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $allWorkers[] = array(
                          'id'=> $row["id"],
                          'latitude'=>$row["latitude"], 
                          'longitude'=>$row["longitude"], 
                          'work_radius'=> $row["work_radius"] 
                    );
}



$distance_query = 'SELECT
  *, (
    6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians(:latitude) )
      * cos( radians( latitude) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(:longitude) )
      + sin ( radians(:latitude) )
      * sin( radians( latitude) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM jobs
having distance < :work_radius
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;';


$workers_jobs = array();

$stmt = $conn->prepare($distance_query);

foreach( $allWorkers as $worker)
{
    $stmt->bindParam(':latitude', $worker['latitude']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':longitude', $worker['longitude']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':work_radius', $worker['work_radius']);

    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $workers_jobs[$worker['id']]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $workers_jobs[$worker['id']]['latitude'] = $row['latitude'];
        $workers_jobs[$worker['id']]['longitude'] = $row['longitude'];
    }

}
```

//$workers_jobs hold one row per worker and his job

**UPDATE**

Suppose you have an extra column say "**Shift**"(varchar 50) in jobs table

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| id | latitude  | longitude |  Shift  |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | 51.919438 | 19.145136 | morning |
|  2 | 49.852276 | 15.015519 | evening |
|  3 | 49.208705 | 11.946989 | night   |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

how to include this in your `$distance_query` ? Well binding for IN is a bit tricky so before heading further you must read [this part](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)

```php
$conn = $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM worker");

$allWorkers = [];

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $allWorkers[] = array(
                          'id'=> $row["id"],
                          'latitude'=>$row["latitude"], 
                          'longitude'=>$row["longitude"], 
                          'work_radius'=> $row["work_radius"] 
                    );
}

    //** bind IN  - placeholders**//
    $shifts = ['morning','night'];
    $in = '';

    foreach ($shifts as $i => $item)
    {
        $key    =   ':shift'.$i;
        $in .= "$key,";
    }
    $in = rtrim($in, ',');
    //** bind IN - placeholders end **// 


$distance_query = 'SELECT
  *, (
    6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians(:latitude) )
      * cos( radians( latitude) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(:longitude) )
      + sin ( radians(:latitude) )
      * sin( radians( latitude) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM jobs
 where shift IN (' . $in . ')
having distance < :work_radius
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;';


$workers_jobs = array();

$stmt = $conn->prepare($distance_query);

foreach( $allWorkers as $worker)
{
    $stmt->bindParam(':latitude', $worker['latitude']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':longitude', $worker['longitude']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':work_radius', $worker['work_radius']);

    //** bind IN - values**//
    $shifts = ['morning','night'];
    $in = '';

    foreach ($shifts as $i => $item)
    {
        $key    =   ':shift'.$i;
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $item);
    }

    //** bind IN - values ends**// 


    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $workers_jobs[$worker['id']]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $workers_jobs[$worker['id']]['latitude'] = $row['latitude'];
        $workers_jobs[$worker['id']]['longitude'] = $row['longitude'];
    }

}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($workers_jobs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, this is doing it for all workers and jobs. I only need to do it for one worker at a time. So in the $result is need to select one worker by ID then match up jobs based on that worker's location and work radius.

Comment: This works for single too just pass id of the worker so it will select only one worker and find jobs for only that worker . `$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM worker where id=$worker_id");`

Comment: how could this be made to accept another parameter. for example: `FROM jobs WHERE something IN (:something) having distance < :work_radius`